# Can you compare a string and a string from a vector?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, vector, iostream

I'm new to C++. Whenever I try to compare a string and a string from a vector, it gives me an error. I included two examples below. Why does this happen?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string vowels = ("aeiou");
  std::string whale_talk = "turpentine and turtles";
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  for (int i = 0; i < whale_talk.size(); i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < vowels.size(); x++) {
      if (whale_talk[i] == vowels[x]) {
        std::cout << whale_talk[i];
        result.push_back(whale_talk[i]);
        // I'm aware I'm not comparing two vectors, I added this to show that most interaction with strings will also result in an error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector <std::string> string_vector;
  std::string string = "Hello";
  std::cout << "What do you want today?";
  string_vector = {"pickles"};
  if (string[2] == string_vector[0]) {
    std::cout << "No pickles today";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "We only have pickles";
  }
}
```

I tried adding and removing `#include <string>`, but that did not help. I also tried putting strings inside the vector before comparing it to a string.

Comment: When you find yourself writing "It gives me an error", always make sure you are including the exact error message in your question.

Comment: And very briefly: when you have a string `foo`,  `foo[i]` is a `char`, not another string.  So pushing `whale_talk[i]`, which is a `char` into `result`, which is an array of `string`, is a type mismatch.  Your compiler should have complained about this in a pretty detailed way, didn't it?

Comment: In the first example you are not comparing strings, you are comparing individual characters. This is not as problem by itself, but then you are trying to push a character to a vector of strings. A character is not a string. In the second example you are trying to compare a string and a character.

Comment: If `str` is a string then `str[i]` is a character, not a string. You say you are comparing strings with strings but you are not.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

```
result.push_back(whale_talk[i]);
```

This is probably the problem with your code for the first example because although whale_talk is a string, using the `operator[]` takes a single character from it and you try to add it into the vector of strings result. This creates a type mismatch between char and string, which may have created your error. If you want to enter the entire whale_talk string into the vector result, just remove the `[i]`. If you want to enter just the character, the best way is probably doing:

```
string temp;
temp = temp + whale_talk[i];
result.push_back(temp);
```

**Problem 2**

```
if (string[2] == string_vector[0])
```

This is probably the problem with your code in the second example because `string[2]` is again a character, but `string_vector[0]` is the first string in your vector of strings. You cannot compare the different types of char and string, which probably created your error. If you want to compare the string with the `string_vector[0]`, just remove the `[2]`.

The general type of problem is probably because of the mismatch of types as present in both examples, so make sure you are comparing a string and a single string from the vector, not a char and a string or a string and a vector.

Comment: I hope this answer helps, Travis Games. For a more precise answer, please post your exact error line in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string vowels = ("aeiou");
    std::string whale_talk = "turpentine and turtles";
    std::string result; 
    //std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < whale_talk.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < vowels.size(); x++) {
            if (whale_talk[i] == vowels[x]) {
                std::cout << whale_talk[i];
                result.push_back(whale_talk[i]);
                // I'm aware I'm not comparing two vectors, I added this to show that most interaction with strings will also result in an error
            }
        }
    }
}
```